# Google SignIn State

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to build a Google signin button into my website.  I'm trying to avoid using their built-in button.  The code below works to sign in a user, but I can't figure out how to make my webpage remember that they're signed in when the user refreshes the page, or leaves the site and comes back.

Using Chrome's developer tools, I can see that there's an entry for `https://accounts.google.com` under both `Local Storage` and `Session Storage`.  They seem to more or less contain the same information, including the user's validated token.

What I don't understand is how to get the `gapi.auth2.init()` function to recognize and use this token.  The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2) doesn't seem to cover it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>
    </head>

    <script>
        var googleUser = {};
        function renderButton() {
            gapi.load('auth2', function(){
                auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: 'MY_CREDENTIALS.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                });
                attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
            });
        };

        function attachSignin(element) {
            auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
                function(googleUser) {
                    document.getElementById('name').innerText = "Signed in: " +
                        googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
                }, function(error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
                }
            );
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <div id="gSignInWrapper">
            <span class="label">Sign in with:</span>
            <input type="button" id="customBtn" value="Google"></input>
        </div>
        <p id="name"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [listeners](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners). This is the relevant part:

```
// Listen for sign-in state changes.
auth2.isSignedIn.listen(signinChanged);

// Listen for changes to current user.
auth2.currentUser.listen(userChanged);
```

You can also get up to date values by

```
var isSignedIn = auth2.isSignedIn.get();
var currentUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
```

To strictly detect returning users only you can do:

```
var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init(CONFIG);
auth2.then(function() {
  // at this point initial authentication is done.
  var currentUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
});
```

When it comes to your code I would do:

```
auth2 = gapi.auth2.init(CONFIG);
auth2.currentUser.listen(onUserChange);
auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {});
```

This way all changes in sign-in state are passed to onUserChange (this includes returning users, new sign-ins from attachClickHandler, new sign-ins from different tab).

Comment: I inserted the auth2.currnetUser.listen(onUserChange); and got an error stating that onUserChange wasn't defined.

Comment: auth2.currentUser (you've got currnet). You have to implement onUserChange handler yourself. Check onSignIn function on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue I was having :)