# Check for returning users. Google sign-in session (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google sign-in using their new API : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Sign in, out, and displaying user data works fine. 
**I'm having trouble to make my webpage remember that a user is signed in when refreshes the page or leaves the site and comes back**. I'll like to show (in console, for example) the user data, hide button etc..

It seems I have to use [listeners](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners) as [explained here, and marked as solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925256/google-signin-state), but still can't make it work.
This is what I have currently working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>  
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="***.apps.googleusercontent.com">

  <script type="text/javascript">    
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();    
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
  }
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();      
      auth2.disconnect().then(function () {        
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="but" class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
  <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
</body>
</html>
```

As I've been here for a while, will really apreciate a full working example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a callback on loading platform.js and are not initializing your client.  Change your include to:

```
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=startApp" async defer></script>
```

Then you can perform any post-initialization steps in **startApp**, for example:

```
function startApp() {
  gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    gapi.client.load('plus','v1').then(function() {
      gapi.signin2.render('signin-button', {
          scope: 'profile',
          fetch_basic_profile: false });
      gapi.auth2.init({fetch_basic_profile: false,
          scope:'profile'}).then(
            function (){
              console.log('init');
              auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
              auth2.isSignedIn.listen( function() {
                  console.log(auth2.currentUser.get());
                });
              auth2.then(function(resp){
                  console.log(auth2.currentUser.get());
                });
            });
    });
  });
}
```

I put together [a demo here](https://gusclass.com/demos/button2).

Comment: Yes. I forgot the first line you have mentioned.
Thank you for your demo, but a priority I have is not to use the Google+ sign in, because the permissions about "circles" can't be eliminated and annoy some users.
In any case your demo might help. Seems I need to implement [Migrate from Google+ Sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/quick-migration-guide)
If I can, will post full code and check your answer as solved.

Comment: To exclude Google+, you just need to change your scope, I updated the example code. Note that the button renders as blue instead of red when you aren't using Google+ scopes.